# How can I use return data set a new parameters in batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I am using the below to get the folder and go to the folder:

```
dir /b /t /a:d >folder.tmp
for %%i in (folder.tmp) do (
  cd %%i
 )
```

But I can not go to folder.

There are some folder (can not know folder list), how can I get those information and use get information to set another parameters by batch file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that you've got it, your `cd %%i` command is going to execute exactly once.

To make `FOR` open the file you need to use the `/F` option.

I'd also suggest you put the a few `echo` commands in temporarily to see what's going on.

```
dir /b /t /a:d >folder.tmp
for /F %%i in (folder.tmp) do (
  echo i is %%i 
  cd %%i
 )
```

(remove the echo line when you've got it doing what you want)

SS64.com is a great resource for batch files: https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html